# Date Issue (DATETIME)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a flat file with the Date column in the below format

```
StartDate
-------------
11/1/2014 0:00
6/09/2013 0:00
```

I am having two Issues with this.

1. When I create a table in SQL server and try and Bulk Insert the files I am getting a Data conversion Error. I have the Start Date Column defined as DATETIME in the table.
2. I need to separate the date and time and obtain the date in mm/dd/yyyy instead of m/d/yyyy

Please advice me with the correct steps to achieve the above results.

Comment: You seem to have given up fairly quickly... have you tried to rectify this yourself at all? *What exactly* have you tried?

Comment: What data is causing the error?  Does this need to be handled entirely in sql?

Comment: I am new to SQL and haven played much with the DATE formats. I imported the file with the column defined as VARCHAR but, not able to convert it into DATE format to extract the date then.

Comment: Yes all this process needs to be carried in sql

Answer (score 0):

```
;with t (theDate) as
(
    select '11/1/2014 0:00' union all
    select '6/09/2013 0:00' 
)
select 
    _datetime = convert(datetime, theDate, 101),
    _date = convert(date, theDate, 101),
    _time = convert(time, theDate, 101)
from t
```

Look at the MSDN documentation for the CONVERT() function. You'll see that it optionally accepts an integer as it's last parameter to convert from a bunch of pre-defined date masks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx